# How to replace a character with carriage return in vim

Tags: vim

If you use `\r` or `^M` in the replacement part of a substitution in vim, it inserts a newline. So how do I insert an actual carriage return character as part of the substitution?

EDIT:

This is specifically in the context of the `:s` command. So I want to do something like `:s/\\r/<CR>` but actually insert a carriage return (0x0d) instead of a line feed (0x0a).

Comment: In the question [how-to-replace-a-character-by-a-newline-in-vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-by-a-newline-in-vim), there is some discussion about replacing with a carriage return character, and @codeshot's answer explains why you cannot replace a character with ,<CR> (0x0d).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in the help page for the `:s` command (or more specifically for sub-replace-expression):

> ```
>   \<CR>     insert a carriage-return (CTRL-M)
>             (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)          *s/\<CR>*
> ```

so to replace with a carriage return (0x0d) I need to type `\<C-v><CR>`